# How to save the API data to the MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

This is my react code that to show all the data from the API. The Card show all the array data from the API.

```
export default class Home extends Component{
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        users:[],
        };
      }

 componentDidMount() {
   axios
   .get("http://localhost:5000/getNews1") 
   .then(response =>{
     this.setState({users:response.data.articles});
    })
 }

 handleSubmit(){}

     render(){
       const news = this.state.users.map((item, i) =>{
         return(
           <Col sm="4">
             <div key={i}>
               <Card id="size">
                 <CardImg top width="100%" src={item.urlToImage} alt={item.title} />
                <CardBody>
                  <CardTitle>{item.title}</CardTitle>
                  <CardSubtitle id="subtitle">{item.description}</CardSubtitle>
                  <CardText>{item.content}</CardText>
                  </CardBody>
                  <CardFooter>
                  <Button id="save_btn" onClick ={this.handleSubmit}>Save</Button>
                  <Button id="read-btn" href={item.url} target="_blank">Read More</Button>
                  </CardFooter>
                </Card>
                <br/>
               </div>
           </Col>
        )
       })   
      return(
       <div>
         <Container>
          <Row>
           {news}
          </Row>
         </Container>
        </div>
       )         
     }
   }
```

Question 
1. How do i get the current card data by click the save button.
2. After get the current card data, how to post it to the backend server

Answer (score 0):

You can't access mongodb directly from the client. 
Your `handleSubmit` should make a "POST" request to some endpoint you have to define/implement on your server. Within this handler you can write the data (JSON?/form data?) to the mongodb.

Super simplified code:

`// server.js
// assuming express server
app.post('/user', async (req, res) => {
  const payload = req.body
  await writeToDb(payload)
  return res.status(200)
})`

`// client component
handleSubmit = async () => {
  await fetch('/user', {
     method: 'POST'
     data: // something from this.state
  })
}`